# Hyperlink not working using Range to HTML function

Tags: html, vba

Using some VBA to grab a table of information and paste to the body of an email using range to html. The problem seems to be with the hyperlink, since the function is just grabbing it as text and formatting it accordingly. The vba i'm using is:

```
Sub Archive_Send()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim rngTo As Range
    Dim rngSubject As Range
    Dim rngBody1 As Range
    Dim StrBody As String
    Dim StrBody1 As String

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next

    Set rng = Sheets("Posting").Range("B5:C55").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    Set rngTo = Sheets("Email").Range("C5")
    Set rngSubject = Sheets("Email").Range("C3")
    Set rngBody1 = Sheets("Email").Range("C13")

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = rngTo.Value
        .Subject = rngSubject.Value
        .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & rngBody1.Value & "" _
         & RangetoHTML(rng) _
         & "<br><br>Best Regards,<br><br></font></span>"
        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1
End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy") & ".htm"

    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    TempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: what happens if you comment out the portion which does the `PasteSpecial`?

Comment: Hi - actually I was able to work around this by just adding some lines to grab the hyperlink in the cell and display it above the table from the html to range function:

  .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & rngBody1.Value & "<br></br><br></br>" _
 & "<a href=" & JobLink.Hyperlinks(1).Address & ">Click here to view posting</a><br></br><br></br>" _

Answer (score 1):

The code rangetohtml works for me with hyperlinks just after making little change shown below:

Use `.Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll, , False, False`

instead of line `.Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPastevalues, , False, False`

Function re-written with said changes as below:

```
    Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        Dim fso As Object
        Dim ts As Object
        Dim TempFile As String
        Dim TempWB As Workbook

        TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy") & ".htm"

        rng.Copy
        Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
        With TempWB.Sheets(1)
            .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
            .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll, , False, False
            .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
            .Cells(1).Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            On Error Resume Next
            .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With

        With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
             SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
             Filename:=TempFile, _
             Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
             Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
             HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
            .Publish (True)
        End With

        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
        RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
        ts.Close
        RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                              "align=left x:publishsource=")

        TempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False

        Kill TempFile

        Set ts = Nothing
        Set fso = Nothing
        Set TempWB = Nothing

    End Function
```

Let me know if this solves your concern. :)